# Склонение двойных собственных имен

Tags: склонение

Как склоняется двойное имя Евгения Агелина?

Comment: Русская традиция — называть народившегося только одним именем. Оно может быть сложным (Марианна, Вероника) , но никак не составным. Второе имя даётся церковью при крещении. Оно — не для формальных записей.

Answer (score 2):

Оба имени **склоняются**, так как соответствуют по форме склоняемым существительным, но возможны **два варианта записи**:Евгения-Агелина и Евгения Агелина.

В первом случае это **двойное имя**, именно так называют Евгению-Агелину, а во втором случае мы имеем два имени, и поэтому выбирают одно из имен.

**Пример:** "Аллу Викторию я всегда называю полным именем, чтобы она с детства понимала, что у нее красивое имя", – признался Киркоров. В этом случае имя должно писаться через дефис.

А вот правильная запись: Малышка получила двойное имя Алла-Виктория.

**Двойные имена:** [Двойное имя для девочки: необыкновенные имена | fb.ru](http://fb.ru/article/257515/dvoynoe-imya-dlya-devochki-neobyiknovennyie-imena)

Comment: Если у ребенка два имени Алла Виктория, то разве нельзя сказать, что ее **полное** имя -  Алла Виктория?

Comment: Это именно полное имя, но существует еще двойное имя с дефисным написанием. Здесь, наверное, важна запись в документах, по ней определяется какое это имя - полное или двойное. Но если девочку называют Алла-Виктория, то имя двойное. Мне кажется, что в приведенном примере под полным именем имелось в виду двойное имя. Возможно, эти термины не всегда различаются, но в письменной записи различие надо учитывать.

Comment: Цитировать здесь Киркорова в пример? Это что-то свеженькое.

Comment: Просто хорошо известный пример двойного имени, есть тексты с разной записью, удобно показать разницу между  двумя вариантами имен.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько понимаю, тут начали повышенное внимание уделять форме записи. Но это надуманная проблема. Иностранные имена записываются с пробелом, это **два имени**. 
В российской традиции имя всегда одно, но в исключительных случаях может быть составным, в этом случае записывается через дефис.

Что имеется в виду в вашем случае, не совсем ясно, но **в любом случае склоняются оба имени**. Сложности могут возникнуть в двух случаях: когда через дефис записывается одно имя со специфической частью, которая сама по себе именем не является (ну, например, в "аль-Багдади", аль - не имя, а артикль), и когда одна (или обе части) не склоняются по грамматическим причинам.

Наш случай не подпадает ни под одну из этих оговорок.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова не надо извинений, спасибо за правку. Я переоценил свое самочувствие, "поплыл", нужен был отдых, а текст жалко было. вот сейчас вернулся, а уже на все  готовенькое Короче, вы меня просто опередили.)))