# Как склоняется имя Виллем-Александер?

Tags: склонение, ономастика, заимствования

По правилам, если имя пишется через дефис, то склоняется только вторая его часть (или первая, если вторая не склоняется): *про Жан-Поля*, *Жак-Ива* и т. д.

Обе части имени склоняются, только если они пишутся раздельно, без дефиса. Но это точно не наш случай, т. к. на языке оригинала дефис присутствует: Willem-Alexander.

Однако что-то внутри меня отказывается склонять на французский манер имя короля Нидерландов и делать из него ***Виллем-Александера***.

Есть ли какие-либо основания склонять обе части этого имени?

Comment: А что это за правило, что склоняется только вторая часть дефисного написания? Ссылочку на источник "правила" не дадите? Я такого не знаю, вот навскидку https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%96%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%96%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE

Comment: @Мимоходов http://gramota.ru/slovari/info/ag/sklon/ 5.1. В сложных западных именах и фамилиях, соединённых дефисом, склоняется последнее слово: БЕЛЬМОНДО Жан-­Поль, Бельмондо Жан-­Поля (франц. актёр); РУССО Жан-­Жак, Руссо Жан-­Жака (франц. писатель и философ); КАПАБЛАНКА Хосе-Рауль, Капабланки Хосе-Рауля [сэ] (кубин. шахматист). Если второе имя не склоняется, то функцию словоизменения принимает на себя первое имя, например: ТРЕНТИНЬЯН Жан-­Луи, Трентиньяна Жана-Луи (франц. актёр); ГЕЙ-ЛЮССАК Жозеф­-Луи, Гей-­Люссака Жозефа-Луи [зэ] (франц. химик и физик).

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Боюсь, это личное мнение "Грамоты". Не думаю, что оно где-то в нормативных источниках. есть. Посмотрю у Розенталя.

Comment: @Андрей  Некоторые мнения по поводу двойных имен можно посмотреть на нашем же сайте: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431347/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd. P.S. У моего отца было двойное имя (или два имени?). Я до сих пор так решить и не могу: отчество (в свидетельстве о рождении и в советском паспорте) — одно. По _первой_ части имени.

Answer (score 1):

Я обратилась на Грамму.ру, пришел ответ.

Здравствуйте, Наталья!

Увы, приходится признать, что рекомендации справочников противоречивы.
Так, в приложении к "Словарю русских личных имен ***А. В. Суперанской (М., 2005)*** даны такие рекомендации: "Если личное имя пишется через дефис, склоняется лишь его последняя часть, несмотря на то что в изолированном употреблении первая часть имени могла бы склоняться: **Р. п. Алим-Паши, Девлет-Гирея и т. п.** Если последняя часть имени относится к несклоняемому типу, а первая может склоняться, она принимает на себя словоизменение: **Р. п. Арслана-Али, Джана-Гиши и т. п.".*** Однако далее сказано: "Если у именуемого два или три имени **(случай, не рекомендуемый современным законодательством, но возможный у иностранцев),** склоняется отдельно каждое имя, если их конечные элементы это позволяют: **Жан-Пьер, Жана-Пьера"...**
На наш взгляд, имеется всё же явная взаимозависимость склонения и написания (дефисного или же раздельного). Рискнем сформулировать ее примерно так:

Если личное имя пишется через дефис, склоняется лишь его последняя часть, несмотря на то что в изолированном употреблении первая часть имени могла бы склоняться: **Р. п. Алим-Паши, Девлет-Гирея, Жан-Жака и т. п.** Если последняя часть имени относится к несклоняемому типу, а первая может склоняться, она принимает на себя словоизменение: **Р. п. Арслана-Али, Джана-Гиши, Пьера-Анри, Шарля-Мари и т. п.**
Если части личного имени пишутся раздельно, то склоняются все его части, способные к словоизменению: **Ханса Кристиана Андерсена, Этьена Мориса Фальконе и т. п.**

Иначе говоря, следует писать и склонять примерно так: ***Виллем Александер, Виллема Александера,*** но: **Виллем-Александер, Виллем-Александера.**

​Следует также отметить, что для написания многих имен (дефисное оно или раздельное) есть традиция, закрепленная в словарях.

​Если же такой традиции нет, то следует ориентироваться на правило, сформулированное в издании **"Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник": ​**

​"
§ 123. Пишутся раздельно:

...

3. Двойные, тройные и т. д. нерусские (европейские, американские) составные имена, напр.: Гай Юлий Цезарь, Жан Жак Руссо, Джордж Ноэл Гордон Байрон, Генри Уордсуорт Лонгфелло, Чарлз Спенсер Чаплин, Хосе Рауль Капабланка, Эрих Мария Ремарк, Иоанн Павел II.

   Примечание. По закрепившейся традиции некоторые имена пишутся через дефис, напр.: Франц-Иосиф, Мария-Антуанетта​"​
   .

​Иначе говоря, если написание двойного, тройного и т. д. имени не освящено традицией, то писать его следует раздельно и склонять его части в соответствии с тем типом склонения существительных, к которому эти части принадлежат.
С уважением
GRAMMA.RU

Answer (score 0):

Пока могу сказать только то, что мне совершенно сознательно хочется склонять обе части имени. Дефисное там написание или нет, но это два самостоятельных имени. Насчет конкретно Виллема-Александра сказать не могу, но на моей памяти всяких Жанов-Жаков и Анну-Марию исправно склоняли по частям.

//---

Андрей, не знаю как Вам, но мне достаточно понятно, что "Грамота" опять накосячила. Формулировок, подобных "грамотной" нет нигде, а вот как этот пункт изложен у Розенталя в "Справочнике по стилистике"

> 2. Иностранные имена на согласный звук склоняются независимо от того, употребляются ли они самостоятельно или вместе с фамилией, например:
>      романы Жюля Верна (не «Жюль Верна»), рассказы Марка Твена, пьесы Джона
>      Бойнтона Пристли, сказки Ханса Кристиана Андерсена, книга Пьера-Анри
>      Симона. Частичные отступления наблюдаются при двойных французских
>      именах, например: философские воззрения Жан-Жака Руссо, вечер памяти
>      Жан-Ришара Блока (первое имя не склоняется, см. § 13, п. 3).

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#%D0%B7_06 
(§151.2)

То есть у Р. речь идет исключительно о французских двойных именах (а чем они лучше, скажем голландских?), а во-вторых, как можно понять, это лишь частичное отступление, не норма, то есть склонение возможно даже в этом случае.

И там же (§13.2)

> При склоняемости первого имени оно пишется раздельно, например: Антуан
>   Франсуа Прево д’Экзиль (писатель XVIII века).

(Судя по всему, вы с этими источниками знакомы, зря не указали в вопросе, меньше было бы сомнений)

То есть получается, что рекомендация Розенталя предлагает в подобных случаях писать раздельно, не ориентируясь на язык-источник. Этим снимается ваш довод, что в голландском с дефисом, поэтому общий принцип неприемлем.
А больше тут уже и зацепиться не за что.

Надеюсь, это вас убедит больше, чем формальное "разрешение" от G.A., ибо мне её подход не то что не нравится, он просто неприемлем.

=== 
@Серж, ну читайте же внимательно, что на самом деле говорит "Грамота" - и что вы цитируете.    ***"Грамота" противоречит Розенталю***, а вы даже не понимаете смысла написанного.

> Т. е. имена через дефис не склоняются.

Грамота утверждает обратное. Склоняются. Вы или не поняли смысл, или исказили его.

> Грамота.ру права

Разумеется, нет. Но она и не говорит, того, что вы приписали. Она всего лишь "творчески дополняет" Розенталя.

> соединённых дефисом, склоняется последнее слово

(полностью - см. выше).

**Итак, имена, соединенные дефисом, *СКЛОНЯЮТСЯ*. Это и по "Грамоте", и по Розенталю, и по здравому смыслу (расходятся они только в способе склонения).**

Розенталя я уже процитировал. Не вижу смысла в дальнейшем.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65643/discussion-on-answer-by------).

Comment: Пожалуйста, старайтесь избегать резких умозаключений об ответах других участников. Если указать на ошибку необходимо, оставьте соответствующий комментарий.

Answer (score 0):

Вначале об "Александере".

Я тоже, упоминая фильм Бергмана, писала "Фанни и Александер", точно воспроизводя шведское написание, но нет, не проходит номер, по-русски Александер - Александр.

> «Фа́нни и Алекса́ндр» (швед. Fanny och Alexander).
>
> ---
>
> Виллем Александр Пауль Фредерик Лодевейк (нидерл. Willem Alexander
>   Paul Frederik Lodewijk; 19 февраля 1817 — 23 ноября 1890) — король
>   Нидерландов и великий герцог Люксембургский с 17 марта 1849 года,
>   герцог Лимбургский.
>
> ---
>
> Виллем-Александр (нидерл. Willem-Alexander), полное имя —
>   Виллем-Александр Клаус Георг Фердинанд (Willem-Alexander Claus George
>   Ferdinand.

Теперь о склонении. Да та же Грамота.ру выносит отдельным пунктом несклоняемую первую часть **французских** имён! Другие источники ей не противоречат.

Зато информации о Виллеме-Александре, склоняемом, полно...

> История любви нидерландского крон-принца **Виллема-Александра** и
>   аргентинской «Золушки» Максимы ─ настоящая сказка... У этой,
>   безусловно, харизматической королевской пары в 2017 году сразу два
>   юбилея: 50-летие короля **Виллема-Александра** и 15-летие со дня их
>   свадьбы, ради которой обоим пришлось через многое пройти.

**[источник](http://www.marieclaire.ru/psychology/king-willem-alexander-and-queen-maxima-love-story/)**

---

Более **[надёжный источник](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80)** - Википедия:

> 31 марта 2001 года Беатрикс и принц Клаус объявили о помолвке своего
>   старшего сына, принца Оранского **Виллема-Александра** и аргентинки
>   Максимы Соррегьеты.

---

> Супруга **Виллема-Александра** Максима стала королевой Нидерландов, а
>   старшая дочь королевской четы, принцесса Катарина-Амалия, —
>   наследницей престола и получила титул принцессы Оранской.

Так что склоняйте обе части имени нидерландца в своё удовольствие!

Comment: *Теперь о склонении. Да та же Грамота.ру выносит отдельным пунктом несклоняемую первую часть французских имён!* - Вы в состоянии понять то, что написано у Андрея по ссылке в 5.1? Какие там еще "несклоняемые части французских имен"?

Comment: Насчет Александера. Если нидерландское имя Александер переиначивать в русского Александра, то боюсь предположить, что ждет имя Виллем.

Comment: Нидерландское имя Alexander передается на русский как **Александер** (Лидин, "Иностранные фамилии и личные имена", стр. 233). 
Если вы считаете Википедию надежным источником, то я благодарю вас за ваше мнение. Давно не видел такого, чтобы на Вики ссылались в вопросах языкознания.

Comment: @Андрей на Вики, как и на все другие источники можно ссылаться в любых вопросах, но всё дело в том, что Вики вообще ничего не говорит по о правилах, из-за которых, собственно, и разгорелся сыр-бор. А вообще подход у G.А. довольно странный, ссылаясь на грамоту и вики одновременно, она просто не замечает, что Вики пишет вопреки грамотной рекомендации (и правильно, кстати, желает), но выбирает за эталон именно Вики без всяких объяснений и формальных оснований. Вот так я бы это сформулировал. Но эта общая беда ресурса в его нынешнем виде.

Comment: /боюсь предположить, что ждет имя Виллем/ - Вильгельм, естественно. А какие сомнения? Вопрос в том, надо ли "перекладівать" подобным образом. И ответ, естественно, - нет".